# New html5 canvas attribute with javascript interaction

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, html

I am very interested in creating a dynamic pie chart based on percentages pulled by php from my sql database (these percentages change). Basically the numbers are pulled and percentages factored by php, then the lines are drawn mby JS HTML5 canvas and CSS. If anyone has a better idea on how to do it i would love to hear it. But i guess my question is, how should i go about this? Can someone set me at a good starting point? perhaps a tutorial or something of that sort.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewording your question. Is it worth of developing custom data visualization library or use something available for free?

1. Yes, it is worth of doing. Data Visualization is very active field of development at the moment. It is really interesting and challenging discipline. It requires a lot of optimizations to make charts nice and fast and it has a lot of space to use classic graphs theories algorithms. Yes, I completely support your move.
2. No, you are wasting your time and money. There is bunch of quite established libraries already over internet distributed under GPL & MIT licenses.

If you really want to try to develop your own Pie chart. Find Raphael.js examples and try to improve its Pie.